# Eliminate noise when using spatial join with tolerance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, spatial-join, noise

I have two networks, which doesn't align perfectly with each other, so when I want to attach attributes from one to another, I have to use spatial join with a certain amount of tolerance. However, at the same time, it creates noise due to the tolerance including extra geometry which should not be included, as you can see from the following pictures. As far as I know, it is the problem due to the quality of the two networks. If the two network can align with each other perfectly, I won't have this issue. I wonder if there is a way to eliminate the noise, given the two networks having the quality issue.

[image]

I am using the ArcGIS 10.3.1 Advanced License.

Comment: I used ArcGIS Network Analyst for creating the network, but later I attached the information from another feature class to it by using spatial join with tolerance, which gave me the noise.